# converting ini to array in needed format using parse_ini_file - not getting desired output

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I have data pulled in a query that includes presenter information.  It is formatted like this:

```
[Doe, John undefined]
middle_name = E.
department = Psychology
institution = Special State University
city = Anywhere
state = Texas
country = USA
office_phone = 123-456-7891
cell_phone = 123-789-4578
email_address = John_Doe@there.edu
website = www.johndoe.edu

[Doe, Jane undefined]
middle_name = 
department = Political Science
institution = Special University
city = anywhere
state = Indiana
country = USA
office_phone = 123-456-7891
cell_phone = 568-456-4589
email_address = janedoe@here.edu
website =
```

I really need it to display like this:

John Doe, Psychology, Special State University

Jane Doe, Political Science, Special University
(Each presenter on a separate line)

I have tried this:

`$cleanpresenters = parse_ini_file($data['presenters'])`;

and it produces this in the error log:

```
 parse_ini_file([Doe, John undefined]\nmiddle_name = E.\ndepartment = Psychology\ninstitution = Special State University\ncity = Anywhere\nstate = Texas\ncountry = USA\noffice_phone = 123-456-7891\ncell_phone = \nemail_address = John_Doe@there.edu\nwebsite = \n\n): failed to open stream: File name too long in -File path name.proposalpdf.php on line 21, referer: Filepath name
```

I am pretty much a PHP newbie and don't know what to do next to fix the error and get it to look like I want. There may be only 1 presenter or there may be several so the solution needs to loop until it runs through all the presenters. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: 
Changing to parse_ini_string and echo the array, I get this:

```
Array
(
    [middle_name] => 
    [department] => Political Science
    [institution] => Special University
    [city] => Anywhere
    [state] => Indiana
    [country] => USA
    [office_phone] => 123-456-7891
    [cell_phone] => 568-456-4589
    [email_address] => janedoe@here.edu
    [website] => 
)
```

So far, so good.  How do I now turn it into the format I desire?

Comment: does this variable $data['presenters'] holds file path of that ini file??

Comment: aah you should use parse_ini_string

Comment: Thanks!
Hi, When I use parse_ini_string and echo the array, I get this: 
<code>
Array
(
    [middle_name] => 
    [department] => Political Science
    [institution] => Special University
    [city] => Anywhere
    [state] => Indiana
    [country] => USA
    [office_phone] => 123-456-7891
    [cell_phone] => 568-456-4589
    [email_address] => janedoe@here.edu
    [website] => 
) </code>

So far, so good.  How do I now turn it into the format I desire? I will also add this to the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out based on research and an example someone else had written.

```
 //convert presenter data from array to string  
    $cleanpresenters = parse_ini_string($data['presenters'],TRUE);
    foreach ($cleanpresenters as $name=>$val1) 
    {
            $name = trim($name);
            $presenters[] = $name;
            $convertedPresenters .= "$name, {$val1['department']}, {$val1['institution']}\n";
    };
```

The above did the trick.  Each presenter prints as name, department, institution on a single line. Thanks for the tips and points in the right direction.